# Android How to switch DarkMode(UiMode) for the whole system?

Tags: android

I want to change the ui mode (eneble/disable Darkmode) for the whole android system. I have read about the `UiModeManager` and the `setNightMode()`-Method but this don't work for me. If I try to disable my DarkMode with this code:

```
UiModeManager manager = (UiModeManager) getSystemService(UI_MODE_SERVICE);
manager.setNightMode(UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

nothing changed and my DarkMode is still on.

And when I manually switch off the DarkMode and try to switch it on with this code:

```
UiModeManager manager= (UiModeManager) getSystemService(UI_MODE_SERVICE);
manager.setNightMode(UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
```

it does not switch on.
I also get no errors while debugging. Does anyone have an idea how to switch the darkmode on and off?

Comment: It seems we need permission MODIFY_DAY_NIGHT_MODE for this. However, it says "Permission is only granted to system apps" when I try to add that permission.